# is there any GUI tool to view compiled file with source code?

Tags: linux, debugging, view, elf

for example, i've got a uboot copy and compiled it with a target platform. but i dont have the hardware and debug tool to run the step by step debug.

so, I wonder is there a GUI tool(win/linux) can load these source and elf file ,then i can read the 'compiled c code'.

Answer (score 1):

Use [IDA PRO](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) + [Hex-Rays decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/).

Additionally one can use [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/). It also is equipped with decompiler.

It will give you not the exact C program but what it would try to do to reconstruct C source from the assembly. It is actually not that bad in doing that but it's not a cheap solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can run **objdump -d -M intel path/to/CompiledCprogram** in the terminal window to read the compiled program in assembly code from the **main:** section in the assembly code.

Other than that, you may not able to do much about an already compiled C program.